# Checking dissimilarity between two lists of class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm

I have two lists of the different type of objects with some similar fields.

```
List<BMS_ROAD_INV> List1 = bmsContext.BMS_ROAD_INV.ToList();
List<RoadInventory> List2 = context.RoadInventories.ToList();
```

I have to check if the similar fields in List1 match with similar fields in List2. If there is any dissimilarity, I want to update that field in List1. What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: `What is the most efficient way to do it` By asking a question and including more information... What do you mean by similar fields, what do these data structures look like, what is some example data, and what are the example results. also why do you mean by most efficient, memory, cpu, readability

Comment: Why you want update if similarity is not found. Provide more clarity on the Question.

Comment: @Faisal Nabil Update your question with `RoadInventory`  model structure and with sample data then ask the expected result you wanting. Otherwise its hard to to guess what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var list3 = List2.Except(List1);
```

This will add the objects that are not present in the List1 from the List2 and store it in a variable list3.

Then you can update the List1 using,

```
List1.Add(list3);
```

Comment: Except method would not work for reference type unless you override the `Equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

If need to match similar fields, then you can use Intersect like below:

```
List<BMS_ROAD_INV> list1 = bmsContext.BMS_ROAD_INV.ToList();
List<RoadInventory> List2 = context.RoadInventories.ToList();

var commonUsers = list1.Select(a => a.Field1).Intersect(list2.Select(b => b.Field1));
```

If Field1 is a class, then need to implement IEquatable interface. or you can use Intersect overload which accepts custom [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151)

Another way of finding common data:

```
var commonData = (from objA in list1
               join objB in list2 on objA.Field1 equals objB.Field2
               select objA/*or objB*/).ToList();
```